# `rails server` throws error "cannot load such file" -- sass/logger (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails: 3.2.12
Ruby: 1.9.3p392 (openSuse package)
OS: openSuse 12.3

I just ran `rails new specsheets`. This ran cleanly including the bundle install:

```
<snip>
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1) 
Using i18n (0.6.9) 
Using multi_json (1.8.4) 
Using activesupport (3.2.12) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.12) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.12) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.12) 
Using arel (3.0.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activerecord (3.2.12) 
Using activeresource (3.2.12) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (3.2.12) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.1.0) 
Using rails (3.2.12) 
Using sass (3.2.14) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8) 
Using uglifier (2.4.0) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

When I attempt to start the WEBrick server it throws the following at me:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/logger.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/logger (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/logger.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:23:in `<class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:4:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:16:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/msnyder/bin/ruby/specsheets/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm new to rails so I don't know what to look for. In the past I'd go to the directory in question (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/) and make sure everything was readable by non-root users and groups. This hasn't worked this time around.

I also noticed that my Gemfile mentioned sass-rails 3.2.3 while the installed version is 3.2.6. I modified the Gemfile to reflect this but still get the errors.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

The log directory under the application directory is empty so there is nothing to report from there.

The server starts fine when run with `sudo`. However, as I have this in my own /home directory that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: After your change to 3.2.6, ran you `bundle update rails`?

Comment: Try to remove the ruby version you have installed in your system and install ruby using `rbenv` or `rvm`, then create or bundle it should work fine.

Comment: Just so I'm clear on this, you're suggesting that I uninstall every ruby-related package which is exactly what this is going to require.

Answer (score -1):

Put `sass-rails` above `rails` in your gemfile.

The `sass-rails` gem is trying to setup the logger and cannot find the `Sass::Rails::Logger` class. 
https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/3-2-stable/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb#L23

This is probably because you are calling sass before it has time to setup and autoload.
https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/3-2-stable/lib/sass/rails.rb#L7

Comment: Just did. It initially threw the same error for `coffee_script/source` so I moved that outside of the `:assets` group as well. All this did was give me the `sass-rails` error again.

Comment: Moved `sass-rails` above `rails`. Same result.

Comment: Just to isolate this as a potential problem, try changing ``gem 'rails', '3.2.12'`` to ``gem 'rails', '3.2.16'``

Comment: Are all the file permissions of all of the folders set to your user? ( not root) - do a ``ls -lah`` to check.

Comment: In the application's directory? They weren't, but even after ensuring they were I got the same result.